# SQL statement to find older data between a certain date based on date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm learning SQL and can't seem to figure out how to find data older than 30 days but not older than 60 days. I'm using SQL Server. The below statement shows all emails where it is below the current date. I don't want to solid date/time like 2018-9-9 since I'm putting this in an application for it to send an email automatically to users after 30 days and blocking the account after 60 days.

I have two columns in the database one is the Email_address(nvarchar(50) and the other is AccDate(date)

```
SELECT Email_Address
FROM User_Email_Address
WHERE Email_Address = Email_Address and AccDate <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

I think I need to use Dateadd(day, -30, getdate(); , but not sure how to.

I have two columns in the database one is the Email_address(nvarchar(50) and the other is AccDate(date).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
SELECT Email_Address
FROM User_Email_Address
WHERE AccDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -60, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE());
```

And drop the check `Email_Address = Email_Address` as the e-mail address is always equal to itself.

Comment: Be careful here....using BETWEEN is problematic. Especially when it comes to datetime values. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: `Email_Address = Email_Address` isn't always true. It is equivalent to `Email_Address IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @SeanLange: I think that deleting accounts after 60 days is not that critical. You could warn after -29 days and delete after 61 days to be sure.

Comment: @MartinSmith: yes, but I have no idea what the OP had in mind with that. Since the table has only these 2 columns, the `Email_Address` should be non-nullable and be the primary key. An empty e-mail makes no sense.

Comment: Yes in the situation I agree it is not critical. Pointing it out the OP doesn't use this same pattern when it does matter thinking it will be ok. Not at all saying this doesn't work. Hence...."be careful". :)

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes Thank you this worked for me.I'll change it to -29/-61.

Comment: @SeanLange i'll keep that in mind with between with a date field. I didn't want to put everything on the table here in the question, but this will be going into a bigger table(not much bigger). I'm using this as just a test. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for email addresses with AccDate "older than 30 days but not older than 60 days", then this might be more accurate to use:

```
SELECT Email_Address
FROM User_Email_Address
WHERE AccDate BETWEEN GETDATE() - 30 AND GETDATE() + 60;
```

If you need a reference book to learn SQL, this book was very helpful for me:
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/150930200X/ref=dbs_a_def_rwt_bibl_vppi_i0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/150930200X)

Cheers!

Comment: You should avoid shortcuts for date math like that. It can cause issues. See the first part of [this article](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations).

Comment: This actually didn't work me. I still get dates that are within the 30 day period. I'll look at the book though thank you!

Comment: @SeanLange thanks for the article, I'll check it out. I am not sure why that didn't work. But I am glad you got a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

I gues you could use something like (untested):

```
... WHERE AccDate BETWEEN Dateadd(day, -60, getdate()) AND Dateadd(day, -30, getdate())
```

Does this helps?

Cheers
Nikao

Comment: Be careful here. Between is problematic. Especially when dealing with datetimes. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: I'm considering that he's storing his dates with the right accuracy. If he's not, he'll certainly have issues. But that's not between's problem per say. (read the first comment on the post you mentioned)

Comment: I think -60 day should first param for between

Comment: It will all depends on his business model. I can't tell for sure Sean. Anyway, it's a very simple change in the query to consider or not seconds, milis, etc, it's up to him.
Oto, I guess you're right, I'll make the change to the answer ;)